# Arithmetic In Arithmetic And Power Of Number

Tags: arithmetic

How do i solve arithmetic problem that contain another arithmetic in it and the arithmetic is problem is using power of number?

This is the problem that i run into
$(2^1) + (2^1 + 2^2) + (2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3) ... U_n$

Is it possible to find the Un and Sn ?

Comment: Hint: consider $U_n + 2$ instead. Calculate a few terms. See what you get.

Comment: You haven't mentioned $S_n$ anywhere in the post except the final line, how is it defined?  Are you wanting $S_n = U_1+U_2+\dots+U_n$?

Comment: i'm sorry i mistaken geometric and arithmetic , the post has been edited

Comment: @JMoravitz yes the value of Sn is the sum of all the Un

Comment: please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner i have read the guide many time but i still don't understand how to use it , if possible can you please help me with that , i really appreciate if you help me with that .

Comment: First and most important step in using mathjax: enclose your equations with dollar signs. `$(2^1)+(2^1+2^2)+(2^1+2^2+2^3)$` results in $(2^1)+(2^1+2^2)+(2^1+2^2+2^3)$.  That already takes you most of the way for simple equations.

Comment: thanks ! it worked

Comment: also, \$U_n\$ produces $U_n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

$1=2^1-1$

$1+2 = 2^2-1$

$1+2+4 = 2^3-1$

$1+2+4+8 = 2^4-1$

$1+2+4+8+16 = 2^5-1$

> $1+2+4+\dots+2^n = 2^{n+1}-1$

So then, what is $U_n$?

Now, looking at $S_n$, can you see a similar pattern emerging?

---

Solution:

Given that $1+2+4+\dots+2^n = 2^{n+1}-1$ it follows that $U_n = 2+4+\dots+2^n = 2^{n+1}-2$

Further, we have that $S_n = U_1+U_2+\dots+U_n$

By replacing $U_n$ with what we found earlier and rearranging we have:

> $S_n = (2^2-2)+(2^3-2)+\dots+(2^{n+1}-2) = (2^2+2^3+\dots+2^{n+1})-2n$

Recalling that $1+2+4+\dots+2^n+2^{n+1}=2^{n+2}-1$ and by subtracting $1+2$ from each side, we arrive at:

> $S_n = (2^{n+2}-4)-2n$

Comment: After Trying several time , i finally figured that $Un = 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 .... 2^n = 2^{n+1} - 2$ , thanks so much !!!! but how do i find the Sn ?

Comment: @user6668201 Additional mathjax tip, several commands will only pay attention to the first following character.  If you want additional characters to be recognized, enclose them in braces.  `$2^n+1$` produces $2^n+1$ but `$2^{n+1}$` produces $2^{n+1}$

Comment: i edited my comment several time before removing the ajax when i stuck with that problem , thanks for helping me so much

Comment: Now, notice that $S_n = (2^2-2)+(2^3-2)+(2^4-2)+\dots+(2^{n+1}-2)$.  Let's rearrange that as $(2^2+2^3+2^4+\dots+2^{n+1}) - 2-2-2-\dots - 2$.  The first section should look very similar to $U_n$ and you should be able to spot that pattern in a similar way.  The second section is just subtracting $2$ a bunch of times.  How many times?

Comment: apparently another solution was $S_n = 2^{n+2} - (n+2)(2) $ , but your answer follow more logical way than this solution